# finding given regex patter in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract a string from a document with the following regex pattern in python.
string will always start with either "AK" or "BK"..followed by numbers or letters or - or /(any order)
This string pattern can contain anywhere in the document

```
document_text="""
This is the organization..this is the address. 
some information
AK3418CPMP
lot of other information down
"""
```

```
I have written following code.
pattern="(?:AK|BK)[A-Za-z0-9-/]+"
res_list=re.findall(pattern,document_text)
```

but I am getting the list contains AKs and BKs
something like this

```
res_list=['AKBN','BKCPU','AK3418CPMP']
```

```
it is also matching the words "AKBN", "BKCPU" along with the required "AK3418CPMP". I want conditions to be following to extract only 1 string "AK3418CPMP": 
1.string should start with AK or BK 
2.It should followed by letters and numbers or numbers and letters 
3.It can contain "-" or "/"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Use a non capture group `(?:AK|BK)[A-Za-z0-9-/]+` or shorted it to `[AB]K[A-Za-z0-9-/]+`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think it's `[AB]K`, not `A[BK]`.

Comment: Thanks but doing that it's also matching the words "AKBN", "BKCPU" along with the required "AK3418CPMP". I want conditions to be following:
1.string should start with AK or BK
2.It should followed by letters and numbers or numbers and letters
3.It can contain "-" or "/"
I would really appreciate the help